# Рендер текста markdown в django проекте

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, поиск-библиотек, markdown

У меня есть простенький проект на `Django`, в котором можно записывать и сохранять в БД какие-то тексты. Мне нужно, что бы эти тексты отображались не в сыром виде, а рендерились как `Markdown`.

Как это реализовать?

***P.S.:*** В текстах будет содержаться `Markdown`-разметка соответственно.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/39712/

Answer (score 1):

Есть библиотека [django-markdown](https://pypi.org/project/django-markdown/)

[здесь](https://klen.github.io/git-markdown.html) описание на русском

Answer (score 0):

models.py

```
class Page(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    markdown_field = models.TextField()
    html_field = models.TextField(editable = False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self):
        self.html = markdown(self.markdown_field)
        super(Page, self).save()
```

html:

```
<html>
<head>

<title>Привет!</title>

</head>

<body>
    <h1>{{ page.name }}</h1>

    <br />

    <p>{{ page.html_field|safe }}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Должен быть установлен пакет [Markdown](https://pypi.org/project/Markdown/)

Comment: Не получается, изменил модель как вы показали, разметку тоже. Сначала django потребовал установить default значение для поля html_field. После чего посты смогли добавляться, но текст не обрабатывался как в markdown